# python dictionary, make every odd number line to key and even number line to value from a file

Tags: python, dictionary, fasta, fastq

**Hi, I have a text file like this:**

```
>NM_145914.2:212
TCTGATGGTAAAAGTCGAGGAGAAAGAAGA
>NM_000614.3:1086
ATTCAATTTAAAATCAGACTCTTTAGTTGA
>NM_012096.2:2808
CAGTTAAGGTTTCAAATTGTGGCAGGTGGT
>NM_173465.3:1682
GTGCGTCGGGTGAGAGAGGCCCCAGCGGCC
>NM_001198858.1:490
CAACCACCACAACCTGCTGGTCTGCTCGGT
......more lines in same style......
```

**What I want is:**

read from above file, make line 1,3,5,7 ... to dictionary keys and line 2,4,5,8... to dictionary values.

**My code is:**

```
query_dict = {}
nameAt = 1
sequenceAt = 2

while name in range(totalLines):
line1 = linecache.getline(filename, nameAt)
line2 = linecache.getline(filename, sequenceAt)

query_dict[line1] = line2
nameAt  = nameAt + 2        
sequenceAt = sequenceAt + 2
```

The code worked, but its very slow, as the minimal lines of my text file is 200,000 lines. does anyone have better method to do this?

Thanks very much.

==============added follow-up question==================

here is fastq format, with 4 lines per read (record):

```
@>NM_052972.2:11:1054:1780:889
CTTCGACATCTCCGGCAACCCCTGGATCTG
+>NM_052972.2:11:1054:1780:889
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@>NM_080660.3:12:914:1802:542
CCTGTATGGCTACTGCAACCTCAAGGATAA
+>NM_080660.3:12:914:1802:542
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@>NM_176814.3:712:2706:4242:98
ACAGAGTAAAAGAGAGGCTGACTTAATAAA
+>NM_176814.3:712:2706:4242:98
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
...... more lines in same style ......
```

i want to create a dictionary, the key is 1st line and the value is 2nd line in each 4 lines of record.

the dictionary would look like:

```
{'@>NM_052972.2:11:1054:1780:889':'CTTCGACATCTCCGGCAACCCCTGGATCTG', 
 '@>NM_080660.3:12:914:1802:542':'CCTGTATGGCTACTGCAACCTCAAGGATAA',
 '@>NM_176814.3:712:2706:4242:98':'ACAGAGTAAAAGAGAGGCTGACTTAATAAA',
 ..... more keys and values ......
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    query_dict = {line.strip():next(f).strip() for line in f}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(query_dict)
{'>NM_000614.3:1086': 'ATTCAATTTAAAATCAGACTCTTTAGTTGA',
 '>NM_001198858.1:490': 'CAACCACCACAACCTGCTGGTCTGCTCGGT',
 '>NM_012096.2:2808': 'CAGTTAAGGTTTCAAATTGTGGCAGGTGGT',
 '>NM_145914.2:212': 'TCTGATGGTAAAAGTCGAGGAGAAAGAAGA',
 '>NM_173465.3:1682': 'GTGCGTCGGGTGAGAGAGGCCCCAGCGGCC'}
```

**Update:**

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    dic = {}
    for line in f:
        dic[line.strip()] = next(f).strip()
        next(f);next(f)  #Drop next two lines
from pprint import pprint
pprint(dic)
```

**Output:**

```
{'@>NM_052972.2:11:1054:1780:889': 'CTTCGACATCTCCGGCAACCCCTGGATCTG',
 '@>NM_080660.3:12:914:1802:542': 'CCTGTATGGCTACTGCAACCTCAAGGATAA',
 '@>NM_176814.3:712:2706:4242:98': 'ACAGAGTAAAAGAGAGGCTGACTTAATAAA'}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for you answer, it worked. but just wondering how to add the fastq format to dictionary? the fastq format is similar to what i showed above, but with 4 lines per record. so to add that to dictionary, i need to add 1st line ( as key) and 2nd line (as value) in every 4 lines.

Answer (score 5):

That's a FASTA file. Install Biopython (`pip install biopython`) and parse it:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open('filename.fasta', 'rU') as handle:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta'):
        print(record)
```

Just look at that readable output:

```
ID: NM_145914.2:212
Name: NM_145914.2:212
Description: NM_145914.2:212
Number of features: 0
Seq('TCTGATGGTAAAAGTCGAGGAGAAAGAAGA', SingleLetterAlphabet())
...
```

Comment: +1 - don't reinvent the wheel if there is a tool for the job.

Comment: yes, its a fasta file. I am doing some testings for sequence alignment tools, even the tools would output some figures like 'reported alignment, alignment rate' etc. but i'd like to write some python scripts to exam the .sam output file. I knew biopython and the output gives a lot information, but its not what i want. but thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2068965: `SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta'))` should work then.

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you give bit more details about:SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta')) ? which is the dictionary created?

Comment: @user2068965: It maps sequence IDs to records. Essentially the same thing as the other answers.

Comment: hi, i got it. but it raise ValueError("Duplicate key '%s'" % key). I am now try to remove the duplicate reads from my test file, any better suggestion? thanks.

Comment: @user2068965: Hmm, that's an error that's explicitly thrown. You'll have to use something like this instead then: `{r.id: r for r in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta')}`

Comment: thanks for your help, i gonna remove the duplicate reads from my test file, because it causes conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Or, instead of a dict-comp:

```
from itertools import izip

with open('somefile') as fin:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in fin)
    query_dict = dict(izip(lines, lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = """>NM_145914.2:212
... TCTGATGGTAAAAGTCGAGGAGAAAGAAGA
... >NM_000614.3:1086
... ATTCAATTTAAAATCAGACTCTTTAGTTGA
... >NM_012096.2:2808
... CAGTTAAGGTTTCAAATTGTGGCAGGTGGT
... >NM_173465.3:1682
... GTGCGTCGGGTGAGAGAGGCCCCAGCGGCC
... >NM_001198858.1:490
... CAACCACCACAACCTGCTGGTCTGCTCGGT""".splitlines()
>>> {i: j for i, j in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])}
{'>NM_145914.2:212': 'TCTGATGGTAAAAGTCGAGGAGAAAGAAGA', '>NM_000614.3:1086': 'ATTCAATTTAAAATCAGACTCTTTAGTTGA', '>NM_001198858.1:490': 'CAACCACCACAACCTGCTGGTCTGCTCGGT', '>NM_012096.2:2808': 'CAGTTAAGGTTTCAAATTGTGGCAGGTGGT', '>NM_173465.3:1682': 'GTGCGTCGGGTGAGAGAGGCCCCAGCGGCC'}
```

Use `itertools.islice` if memory is an issue:

```
{i: j for i, j in zip(islice(s, 0, len(s), 2), islice(s, 1, len(s), 2))}
```

Comment: This requires reading the entire file into memory, which is generally poor design as it will cause issues with very large files. `itertools.islice()` also would be no more memory efficient unless you were working from a lazy source.

Comment: The file he talks about is less than 10MB, it wouldn't be an issue. But you're right, there are better ways, I just like slicing.